# Button tap in UICollectionViewCell toggles state in another cell also

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, rx-swift

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that contains a `UIButton`.

When tapping the button in a cell, I want to toggle the `selected` state.

This works to an extent, the bug I am seeing is, clicking in 1 cell toggles the state in another cell also.

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class PersonaliseYourAppsListCell: BaseCollectionViewCell<Launcher> {

    let toggleSelectedTrigger = PublishSubject<String>()

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configureSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    override func render(with model: Launcher?) {
        guard let model = model else { return }

        title.text = model.name
        icon.image = model.icon

        toggleButton.rx.tap.bind { [weak self] in
            self?.toggleButton.isSelected.toggle()
            self?.toggleSelectedTrigger.onNext(model.id)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        if let status = model.status {
            toggleButton.isSelected = model.selected ?? false
            toggleButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = status != .forced

            [title, icon, toggleButton].forEach {
                $0.alpha = status == .forced ? 0.6 : 1
            }

            if status == .forced {
                addSubviews(enforcedLabel)
                enforcedLabel.position(top: title.bottomAnchor, leading: title.leadingAnchor, withPadding: .zero)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        enforcedLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // MARK:- UI Elements

    private func configureSubviews() {
        addSubviews(icon, title, toggleButton, separatorView)

        icon
            .isCenteredY()
            .position(
                leading: leadingAnchor,
                withPadding: .init(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 4)
        )

        title
            .isCenteredY()
            .position(
                leading: icon.trailingAnchor, trailing: toggleButton.leadingAnchor,
                withPadding: .init(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
        )

        toggleButton
            .isCenteredY()
            .withSize(.init(width: 44, height: 44))
            .position(trailing: trailingAnchor, withPadding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 16))

        separatorView
            .isCenteredX()
            .withSize(.init(width: frame.width - 48, height: 1))
            .position(bottom: bottomAnchor)
    }

    private lazy var icon: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        [iv.widthAnchor, iv.heightAnchor].forEach { $0.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true }
        return iv
    }()

    private lazy var title: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textColor = .usingHex("444444")
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var toggleButton: CheckBoxButton = {
        let button = CheckBoxButton(type: .custom)
        return button
    }()

    private lazy var enforcedLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.text = "This app cannot be removed"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.textColor = .lightGray
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var separatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 0.1)
        return view
    }()
}
```

My CollectionView is setup as follows:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        presenter?.viewIsReady.onNext(())

        presenter?.data.bind(to: customView.collectionView.rx.items) { [weak self] (cv, row, item) -> UICollectionViewCell in

            let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: PersonaliseYourAppsListCell.self, for: .init(row: row, section: 0))
            cell.render(with: item)

            if let self = self, let presenter = self.presenter {
                cell.toggleSelectedTrigger.bind(to: presenter.updateUserAppsTrigger).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
            }

            return cell

        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        customView.configureLayout()
    }
```

**EDIT**

I've noticed if I do not make the api call and just let the buttons state toggle, the bug does not exist. I wonder if the response is reloading the collection view and due to re use the wrong button state is being updated.

**EDIT 2**

If I trigger the API call by selecting the cell instead of the button everything works, However I would like this to happen on button click.

I suspect still this is something todo with button state.

[image]

Comment: What do you do in updateUserAppsTrigger function?

Comment: That passes the id of the selected app to a service. I have added some logging in `presenter?.data.bind(to: customView.collectionView.rx.items)` and I can see the `item` prop is correct each time data is passed in. I think this is todo with cell reuse but am not sure how to correct the bug.

Comment: You would be updating your presenter?.data from updateUserAppsTrigger function, right? If so are you sure that the data in items array is valid?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure it is valid, when I log out `item` I can see on each update the props are as expected.

Comment: Have you override the prepareForLayout() method UICollectionViewCell

Comment: At the moment I just remove a view object, but I do not do anything to update the button state. I have tried resetting the state back to default and the bug exists

Comment: I've added some additional findings

Comment: Will your model from api response always have status value? Why has it been treated as optional field?

Comment: It does not, that enrichment happens based on properties in the model

Answer (score 0):

As Subramanian Mariappan suggests, it might be because of cells being reused. In your `render` method you subscribe to button tap and you never actually stop observing. Replace:

```swift
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

with:

```swift
private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

and in `func prepareForReuse()` add creation of a new disposeBag (which will release the old one by the way).

```swift
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        enforcedLabel.removeFromSuperview()

        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
```